# how to set status bar text color when view is presented in iOS using Swift language?

Tags: ios, swift

How to change the status bar text color when the view is presented. I tried using preferredStatusBarStyle override that but the problem not solved. Please let me know if any solution exists for the same problem.

```swift
override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
     return UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
}
```

The preferredStatusBarStyle variable not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, in info Plist add this line

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<true/>
```

[image]

in your view controller call this method[image]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Hope Will Work for you

Answer (score 0):

Go to info.plist and add this key:

```
View controller-based status bar appearance
```

Set it to **YES**

Hope this helps!